# Spark-Cassandra-connector issue: value write is not a member of Unit in BOresultDf.write

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to write a Dataframe into Cassandra using the following code:

```
val BackOfficeDF = spark.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
      .load("/home/user/avro/data/output/backoffice/test.avro")

val uuid = udf(() => java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString)

val BOresultDf = FilteredPSPDF.join(FilteredBackOfficeDF, FilteredBackOfficeDF("ProviderReference") === FilteredPSPDF("orderid"),"full_outer")
      .select( "TransactionId","BOTransactionType","PSPId", "UserId","Status","BOCurrency","BOAmount","Date","ProviderReference")
      .filter(FilteredPSPDF("orderid").isNull)
      .withColumnRenamed("BOTransactionType", "transaction_type")
      .withColumnRenamed("BOCurrency", "currency")
      .withColumnRenamed("BOAmount", "amount")
      .withColumnRenamed("PSPId", "psp_id")
      .withColumnRenamed("ProviderReference", "provider_reference")
      .withColumnRenamed("TransactionId", "transaction_id")
      .withColumnRenamed("UserId", "user_id")
      .withColumnRenamed("Status", "status")
      .withColumnRenamed("Date", "date")
      .withColumn("backoffice_payment_id", uuid())
      .show()

    BOresultDf.write
          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
          .mode("append")
          .option("keyspace","payments")
          .option("table","backoffice_payments")
          .save()
```

I am using the following dependency in SBT:

```
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"
libraryDependencies += "datastax" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.1-s_2.11"
```

Scala version is: 2.11.8

But I am getting error:

```
Error:(80, 16) value write is not a member of Unit
    BOresultDf.write
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how is `BOresultDf` calculated?

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Remove `.show()` from the end and it'll work.

Comment: It worked! Thanks :)